# Transfer XAML Label settings to a Group of Labels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have to create a few Labels and I would be give more View and shorter XAML Code if I can group then and transfer Settings like Background, Height etc with line.

Is there an Option for this?

Somethink like that:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Group Height="25" Background="Red" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
        <Label Name="Header" Content="Test" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Label Name="TextLabel" Content="Some Text" />
    </Group>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This seems to be what styles are for.

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure whether you had already ruled out styles for some reason and you were still looking for yet another solution, or whether you just hadn't come across styles yet. As styles suit your needs, I have described them slightly more thoroughly in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31266901/1430156).

Answer (score 1):

This is what styles should be used for:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LabelStyle">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Label Name="Header" Content="Test" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
    <Label Name="TextLabel" Content="Some Text" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

First, you define a style as a named static resource (the name being *LabelStyle*). The style defines all the common property values that you want to apply to all labels.

Then, you assign that style to the labels by means of the [`Style` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.style%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Or you omit the `x:Key` and only set `TargetType="Label"` and thus create a local default Style for Labels. Then you wouldn't have to explicitly set the Style property of each Label in the StackPanel.

Comment: @Clemens: If the style is desired for all labels, indeed.

Comment: That's how I understood the question.